# Correct column types in Oracle and PostgreSQL for Java(Hibernate) Float type

Tags: java, oracle, postgresql, hibernate

I need create column for storage Float value in Oracle and PostgreSQL.

```
@Column(name = "SOME_VALUE")
private Float someValue;
```

How do I create columns in both bases so that Hibernate is mapping normally?

I tried the `FLOAT` type in Oracle (and it work) and `BIGINT` in PostgresSQL.

But I am confused by my choice. I want the most correct types for both databases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**For Oracle:**

use `NUMBER` for arbitrary precision (if you can't afford rounding errors, for example with money) or `BINARY_DOUBLE` for faster processing, if rounding errors don't matter so much, like a temperature measurement.

**For PostgreSQL:**

The corresponding data types in PostgreSQL would be `numeric` and `double precision`.

`FLOAT` in Oracle is the same as `NUMBER` with a precision limit in binary digits, and `bigint` in PostgresSQL is for large integer numbers.

Comment: I use REAL for bouth bases. When I run script in `oracle` was created `float(63)` and in `postgres` - `real`. Is it wrong or has the right to exist?

Comment: Those are also ok. As I wrote, `FLOAT` is the same as `NUMBER` in Oracle, and `real` is like `double precision`, except with fewer significant digits.